# Altering the style of an NSSearchField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am wondering how I would change the look of an NSSearchField, I am pretty sure it would mean sub-classing NSSearchField, but the bit I don't know how to do is code it to make it the way I want it to look. Below you can see the way I want it to look and how it looks currently.

[alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/3f1r](http://snapplr.com/snap/3f1r)

How would I make it look like this (on the left) by using code?
I am looking to add  that emboss and reduce the inner shadow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a custom NSSearchFieldCell subclass, and override drawWithFrame:, then set your NSSearchField to use that cell. You can either draw your custom border in code, or use end-cap images and a background image for the center that you tile horizontally.

Here's [an example](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla1.8.0/source/camino/src/browser/SearchTextFieldCell.m#170) of old code that used the latter approach to make a custom NSTextField that looked like a search field back before NSSearchField was a standard control.

Comment: See the Cocoa Drawing Guide: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/

Comment: What code would I need to give it that emboss look and remove the shadow?

Comment: I also noticed that the Search Field in Firefox looks like this, is there some source code for Firefox which includes this?

Comment: Firefox doesn't use native OS controls, so its code would probably not be useful to you. As for how to draw it, try reading the "Paths" section from the link that Peter gave you. If you are having trouble using specific drawing routines, try asking new SO questions showing what you are trying and what's non working, rather than asking for people to do all the work for you up-front.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, that field on the left just looks double-struck to me. So you might try just overriding `drawRect:` to send `[super drawRect:]` twice. ☺

(The real test would be if you could show both fields with text in them. Double-struck text is really easy to spot, and is definitely not something you want.)

Comment: What code would I need to give it that emboss look and remove the shadow?
I also noticed that the Search Field in Firefox looks like this, is there some source code for Firefox which includes this?

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to increase the size of `NSSearchField` then you do not need to subclass it, you just create the search field programmatically and give your desired size during `initWithFrame`.

An example is given below:

```
mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,320,70)];
    mySearchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    mySearchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    mySearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    mySearchBar.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:mySearchBar];
```

Or, if you want a different look, specify it; I can help you.

Comment: I want it to have a emboss and I want it to have less of a shadow, look at the picture to see what I mean.

Comment: The op is talking about a NSSearchField (Mac) not a UISearchBar (iOS)